# Percona and MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, percona

Does anyone know if MySQL Workbench will work with a Percona 5.1 server?

If not, can anyone suggest a similar tool that will?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Percona server is fully compatible with MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Doesnt work for me. Percona actually says their support excludes MySQL Workbench on their website:

> Percona MySQL Support excludes coverage for:
>
> The NDB Cluster database and storage engine (available as a separate
>   option) All graphical tools, such as MySQL Workbench

[Source](http://www.percona.com/mysql-support/policies/supported-software)

Frustrating :-(

Navicat does support it, and has modeling features like MySQL Workbench. Unfortunately it isn't free...